# ComboBox is too high

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

If I set the height to something larger it will go over the space dedicated. How can I solve this? Can I somehow take away all the empty space in the combobox?

See picture below. You can't read the text "-Vessel Type-" because of this problem.

[image]

Code:

```
    <ComboBox Name="comboBoxVesselType" Width="152" Margin="8,2,0,0" Height="15" Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" MouseEnter="canvasSelection_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="canvasSelection_MouseLeave">
        <ListBoxItem Content="- Vessel Type- " IsSelected="True" />
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Why are you putting a ListBoxItem inside a ComboBox?

Comment: Have you tried removing the margins?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting a ListBoxItem inside a combobox?

Anyway try negative values for the padding like

```
Paddin="0,-5, 0, 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to template the combo box. Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ComboBox` `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Top`

Example:

```
 <ComboBox VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ....................
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, the item for the ComboBox is not ListBoxItem but ComboBoxItem. That solved it.

```
        <ComboBox Name="comboBoxVesselType" Width="152" Margin="8,2,0,0" Height="15" Padding="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10" MouseEnter="canvasSelection_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="canvasSelection_MouseLeave">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="- Vessel Type- " IsSelected="True" />
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use ComboBoxItem instead ListBoxItem. You can also set Aligments to "Center" and avoid the need to use a fixed Width. That solved it.

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxVesselType" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,2,0,0" Height="15"
Padding="0,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10"
MouseEnter="canvasSelection_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="canvasSelection_MouseLeave">
<ComboBoxItem Content="- Vessel Type- " IsSelected="True" />
</ComboBox>
```